# Separate form array by row added

Tags: php

I have this file upload input in a form:

```
<input type="file"  multiple name="file[]" />
```

I have a script which appends this multiple times within the form.

Could I determine which row each file[] array belongs to in php?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['file'])=== true){
$files = array ($_FILES['file']);
}
    var_dump($files);
```

?>

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'IMG_8502 f 5 .jpg' (length=17)
      1 => string 'IMG_8507 f 5 .jpg' (length=17)
      2 => string 'IMG_8508 f 5 .jpg' (length=17)
      3 => string 'IMG_8529 f 5 .jpg' (length=17)
      4 => string 'IMG_8612 fff 5 .jpg' (length=19)
  'type' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      1 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      2 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      3 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      4 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpE892.tmp' (length=23)
      1 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpE8D1.tmp' (length=23)
      2 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpE911.tmp' (length=23)
      3 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpE950.tmp' (length=23)
      4 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpE99F.tmp' (length=23)
  'error' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 0
      2 => int 0
      3 => int 0
      4 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 2776165
      1 => int 2380025
      2 => int 2456713
      3 => int 2585779
      4 => int 1770128
```

I would like to get each set of files uploaded into their own array. In other words name 0-4 set to be array 0 and then for the next set of files uploaded in the next row to be array 1 and so on. so i can store each set of files with their associated text in the form

Comment: Then what you have tried..??

Comment: please describe more what you have output and what you want, what code you using

Comment: please post what code you using for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])=== true){
  $files = array ($_FILES['userfile']);
  echo  '<pre>';
  print_r($_FILES['userfile']);
  echo  '</pre>';
}
?>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
    set one:<br>
  <input name="userfile[0][]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[0][]" type="file" /><br />
  set two:<br>
  <input name="userfile[1][]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[1][]" type="file" /><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

Test output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
                    [1] => Desert.jpg
                    [2] => Hydrangeas.jpg
                    [3] => Jellyfish.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Koala.jpg
                    [1] => Lighthouse.jpg
                    [2] => Penguins.jpg
                    [3] => Tulips.jpg
                )

        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => image/jpeg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => image/jpeg
                )

        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php4095.tmp
                    [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php40B5.tmp
                    [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\php40C6.tmp
                    [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\php40C7.tmp
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php40D7.tmp
                    [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php40D8.tmp
                    [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\php40D9.tmp
                    [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\php40EA.tmp
                )

        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 879394
                    [1] => 845941
                    [2] => 595284
                    [3] => 775702
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 780831
                    [1] => 561276
                    [2] => 777835
                    [3] => 620888
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: is there anyway you could post the processing code to separate these and put them into a folder

Comment: what do you mean by separate these and put them into folder?

Comment: I would like to save each of these files into a folder by which array number they are...array[0][0], array[0][1] .... array[1][0], array[1][1], so im thinking of how to sort through these in a while loop

Comment: Do you mean the file names should be ([0][0], [0][1]) inside the folder?

Comment: something like that so I could pull them later

Comment: but you loss real file names, or you might join them like ([0][0]_realfilename) ?

Comment: im not sure im following you, I would just like to be able to move each array and sub array into a folder where I could call each one. I really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//This function rearranges the $_FILES array
function rearrangeArray() {
    $newArray = array();

    foreach( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ] as $key => $value ) {
        $newArray[ $key ][ 'name' ] = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ][ $key ];
        $newArray[ $key ][ 'type' ] = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'type' ][ $key ];
        $newArray[ $key ][ 'tmp_name' ] = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $key ];
        $newArray[ $key ][ 'error' ] = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'error' ][ $key ];
        $newArray[ $key ][ 'size' ] = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'size' ][ $key ];
    }

    $_FILES[ 'file' ] = $newArray;
}

if( isset( $_FILES[ 'file' ] ) ) {
    print_r($_FILES);
    rearrangeArray();
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

**$_FILES BEFORE CALLING THE FUNCTION**

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Desert.jpg
                    [1] => Hydrangeas.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC349.tmp
                    [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC398.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 845941
                    [1] => 595284
                )

        )

)
```

**$_FILES AFTER CALLING THE FUNCTION**

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Desert.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC349.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 845941
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Hydrangeas.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC398.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 595284
                )

        )

)
```

Hope it helps.